# VBA - Excel RANDOM formula without the same number being used subsequently

Tags: vba, excel

I created the code below, and it technically works as it should. It puts a random number from 1 to 3 in column C of all the used rows from 84 down. Since it's restricted to only 3 values, I'm getting the same numbers in a row pretty often. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? So if C84 ends up being "2", C85 has to be either "1" or "3"?

```
Sub RandomNumbers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("C84") = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)"
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C84:C" & LastRow) = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the output to be more 'random-ish' then do `RANDBETWEEN(1, 10)` perhaps ? Also you forgot to turn `ScreenUpdating` back on.

Comment: why use Random then, you can populate just 1 2 3 in continuity. Will make more sense.

Comment: It needs to be between 1 and 3 and it can't just be 1, 2, 3. And it needs to be like 21313123123132132...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we want to generate a column of values between 1 and 3 randomly with no sequential repeats.

**Without VBA:**

in **A1** enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)
```

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(A1=1,RANDBETWEEN(2,3),IF(A1=3,RANDBETWEEN(1,2),IF(RAND()<0.5,1,3)))
```

and copy down:

[image]

If you definitely require VBA, then you can use VBA to paste the formulas.

Comment: This works! I never would have thought about doing it this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following loop:

```
Sub RandomNumbers()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 84 To LastRow

ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)

    Do Until ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i - 1).Value

    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)

    Loop

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This probably works, but just FYI you can drop the `ActiveSheet.` - it's implied if you don't specify a sheet name.

Comment: Learned something new. Thanks @user1274820